# Custom IN clause

Tags: vb.net, in-clause

I am trying to create a function similar to SQL IN but in VB.net, the problem is that I can not find the safe way to check if it is possible to use operators like '=' or '>' If not else use 'Is' (for control) and 'typeof' For any class in the project, example:

```
Private Function InVB(Tager As Object, ParamArray Items As Object())

    For Each item In Items

        If TypeOf Tager Is some-clase-of-my-project OrElse TypeOf Tager Is A Control Then
            If Tager Is item Then Return True
        Else
            If Tager = item Then Return True
        End If
    Next

    Return False
End Function

' and 

Private Function BetweenVB...
```

Comment: Depending on how you picture this being used, it probably already exists as For Each or a linq method

Comment: I believe `Object.Equals(...)` should accomplish your goal.

Comment: If you are an english-speaker, `Tager` should probably be `Tagger` ?

Comment: targe parameter